# Calling setTimeout in a loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

The following JavaScript ought to (in my mind) play a sequence of notes 0.5 sec apart. But it plays them all as a single simultaneous chord. Any idea how to fix it?

```
function playRecording() {
    if (notes.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
            var timeToStartNote = 500 * i;
            setTimeout(playNote(i), timeToStartNote);
        }
    }
}

function playNote(i) {
    var noteNumber = notes[i];
    var note = new Audio("/notes/note_" + noteNumber + ".mp3");
    note.play();
}
```

Comment: please specify the language used

Comment: This is JavaScript, Tom Swifty :)

Comment: Can you share more of your code?  Where is the notes object getting set?

Comment: Tom Swifty, it says JavaScript on the question... or did he edit it after you asked him...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks folks, and here is the complete solution to my question:

```
function playRecording() {
    if (notes.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
            playNote(i);
        }
    }
}

function playNote(i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var noteNumber = notes[i];
        var note = new Audio("/notes/note_" + noteNumber + ".mp3");
        note.play();
    }, 500 * i);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript closures, wrap this in a self-executing function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) { 
    (function(i) {
       var timeToStartNote = 500 * i;
       setTimeout(function() {
           playNote(i)
       }, timeToStartNote);
    })(i)
}
```

Comment: Why is this up voted? This will execute ```playNote()``` immediately on each loop.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple actually, in the for loop you call the function `playNote(i)` which plays the note i instantaneously (and therefore play many notes instantly like a chord since it is in a really fast running for loop). Instead you should try code this which lets the timeout actually play the note. The `setTimeout` function expects the function as an argument instead you called the function.

```
(function(j){setTimeout(function(){playNote(j);},j*500);}(i));
```