# Weird jQuery behaviour. Mouse down not calling .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$( "#drawingSurface" ).mousedown(function(event) {
 $('.infoText').text('Started! Please Wait..');
 compilation(); // this takes a long time.
}
```

Now no matter what I do, `$('.infoText').text('Started! Please Wait..');` will just not execute. The element is there, it is annoying because compilation takes ages to finish and when it is done then the text shows up. I want the text to SHOW up as in the order that I have written things.

Comment: You can probably use a timeout before compilation so the text would appear

Comment: It's not jQuery's fault; the browser will wait for your event handler to return unless it has to re-render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's executing, but while `compilation` is running, it prevents the browser from updating the display of the page.

You can fix that by introducing a very brief delay between the text update and `compilation`:

```
$( "#drawingSurface" ).mousedown(function(event) {
    $('.infoText').text('Started! Please Wait..');
    setTimeout(compilation, 50);
});
```

That way the browser has a chance to show the change before blocking on the long-running `compilation`. (`0` usually works on Chrome, but Firefox typically needs about `50`. YMMV.)

If you can, consider moving `compilation` to a web worker ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)) so you don't have to block the main UI thread at all.

Comment: still not working... I added $('.infoText').text('started! Please Wait..');
            setTimeout(compilation(foo), 150);

Comment: @TrtTrt: That still [calls `compilation` right away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643714/settimeout-calls-function-immediately-instead-of-after-delay), and then passes its return value into `setTimeout`, exactly like `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`. If you need to pass `foo` to `compilation`, then: `setTimeout(function() { compilation(foo); }, 50)` or `setTimeout(compilation.bind(null, foo))`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the DOM update does not behave synchronously (edit: not exactly, see comments), so it begins executing your function (compilation()) before the text in the div changes. As a workaround, you could add it to a timeout such as the following

```js
$( () => {
  $( "#drawingSurface" ).mousedown(function(event) {
   console.log('hi');
   $('.infoText').text('Started! Please Wait..');
    setTimeout(doWork, 1);
  });
});



function doWork() {
 let i = 0;
  while (i < 1e3) {
   console.log('waiting');
    i++
  }
  $('.infoText').text('Done.');
  console.log('finished');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="drawingSurface">
  Click me
</div>

<div class="infoText">
text
</div>
```

Comment: *"Seems like the DOM update does not behave synchronously, so it begins executing your function (compilation()) before the text in the div changes."* The DOM update is synchronous. The *rendering* of that update is not, and is what's heled up by `compilation`. See my answer.

Comment: I see, so it is due to how the browser handles the change of the DOM that causes the delay?

On a side note, I also noticed that when the doWork() function took a very long time, the text actually updated before the function completed (although it took several seconds for the change to appear).

Comment: Yes, but they've mostly converged on the same model for it, not least for `requestAnimationFrame` support: The rendering is done on the same thread JavaScript runs on, between JavaScript tasks, up to 60 times/second.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you could move '$('.infoText').text('Started! Please Wait..');' to be inside the compilation function.