# Why do I get 'Next is not a function' when I try to export a Middleware function to module.exports object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a middleware function written inside my `logger.js` module which I then import into `app.js` and use

```js
// ------ File : logger.js ------ //

function log(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Logging details ... ');
  next();
}

module.exports = log;

// ------ File : app.js -------- //

const logger = require('./logger');

app.use(logger);
```

The above code works without any issue and my log functionality works. However, if I export this log function in the following way (add it to the `module.exports` object), I get an error

```js
// ------ File : logger.js -------//

function log(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Logging details ... ');
  next();
}
module.exports.log = log;

// ------ File : app.js -------- //

const logger = require('./logger');

app.use(logger.log());
```

```js
Logging details ...
D:\express-demo-worked\logger.js:4
    next();
    ^

TypeError: next is not a function
    at Object.log (D:\express-demo-worked\logger.js:4:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\express-demo-worked\app.js:18:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:738:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can someone explain to me why this behaves differently and how to correct the second code snippet I added here?

Comment: I'm no expert with express, or the ES6 module system - but it appears to me that you've made a simple mistake of making the function call in `app.use(logger.log());` rather than simply passing the function reference: `app.use(logger.log);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*setTimeout calls function immediately instead of after delay*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643714/settimeout-calls-function-immediately-instead-of-after-delay)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.use(logger.log());
```

This will call logger.log immediately, passing in no arguments. Whatever logger.log returns will then be passed into app.use. Since you passed in no arguments, next is undefined, resulting in that exception.

Instead, do:

```
app.use(logger.log);
```

This will pass logger.log into app.use. At some point later, logger.log will be called, passing in the correct arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
app.use(logger.log());
```

you're **calling** `log`, without any arguments, and passing its return value into `app.use`. Since `log` expects and uses its parameters, that will fail on `next()` because the value of the `next` parameter is `undefined`, as you didn't pass an argument for it.

You may have meant just to pass the function in:

```
app.use(logger.log);
// No () ---------^
```