# Adding classes to html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a class to a html element so that when the user selects a certain type from the drop down list on the UI, the border of the 'type' box changes color. I'd thought I had coded it correctly but I can't seem to get it working.

Here's the css:

```
.blue {
    border: px solid blue !important;
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<select class="input_type" name="input_type" style="height:36px" placeholder="Type" required>
                    <option value="Type">Type</option>
                    <option value="health">Health</option>
                    <option value="work">Work</option>
                    <option value="leisure">Leisure</option>
                </select>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
changedType: function(type) {

            if (type === "health") {
                var blueBox = document.querySelector('.inputType');
                blueBox.addClass('blue');

             }

         },
```

Here's where the method is called:

```
document.querySelector(DOM.inputType).addEventListener('change', UICtrl.changedType(usersInput.type));
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You're saying `blueBox.addClass('blue');` but that's the jquery way to add a class. Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: `addClass` is a jQuery function. You want [`.classList.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods).

Comment: `document.querySelector(DOM.inputType).addEventListener('change', UICtrl.changedType(usersInput.type))` **calls** `UICtrl.changedType` and passes its return value into `addEventListener`. If you want to call that function when the event occurs, you need to wrap that in a function. See [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643714/)'s answers, but for instance: `document.querySelector(DOM.inputType).addEventListener('change', function() { UICtrl.changedType(usersInput.type); });` (And, of course, the `addClass` issue raised above.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :) I removed it when I saw your comment, as I agreed. Here's the other dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/507138/215552

Comment: Thanks for all your responses everyone!! I have amended the code to reflect your suggestions but it's still not working? Any other ideas?

Comment: https://codepen.io/khorvatin/pen/VwZVvjm?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks for this @kah608. I implemented your code as a method rather than a function like this: changedType: function(event) { console.log(event.target.value); if (event.target.value === "health") { event.target.className += ' blue'; } else { event.target.className = 'input_type'; } console.log(event.target.className); },       and then I called the method like this:   var el = document.querySelector('.input_type');
            el.addEventListener("change", function() {
                UICtrl.changedType(), false });   but it just says 'Cannot read property 'target' of undefined'

Comment: You're not passing the event from the event listener to your `changedType` function: `el.addEventListener("change", function(e) { UICtrl.changedType(e) }, false);` Note that you also had the `false` in the wrong place.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Thank you so much! This makes sense. Can I ask what the 'false' actually does and why is it necessary to have it there?

Comment: The best place I've found is [MDN's documentation on `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters). You want to look at the `useCapture` parameter.

Comment: Ok cool, I’ll check it out. Thanks for you help again