# I don't get why this code run without error

Tags: javascript

Example 1 seems correct and wrong at the same time because 'x' is not in the scope when 'on' is declared but  it is when test is run. Example 2 i don't know why it's working

Example 1:

```js
on = (callback) => {
        callback()
      }

function test (){
    let x = 'hello'
    
    on(() => {
        console.log(x);
    })
}

test()
```

---

Example 2:

```js
on = (callback) => {
        callback()
      }

function test (){
    let x = 'hello'
    
    on(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {console.log(x)}, 1000);
    })
}
test()
```

i expected an error but the code runs without it

Comment: *" because 'x' is not in the scope when 'on' is declared"* - `on` doesn't use `x` or reference it in any way, so that doesn't matter.  `on` only ever uses `callback`, which is a local variable declared as a parameter of that function.  `x` is used in another function, an anonymous function which is declared/defined in a scope where `x` exists.  That function embodies a closure around `x` and retains a reference to it.

Comment: Note: Javascript captures scope using closures.  Read up on closures here ->  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: As an aside... The two examples don't do anything different.  You may be incorrectly expecting the second example to add a delay, but it doesn't.  The first example is all you need here.

Comment: @David  well spotted, and even if the OP did what they meant, it would still work..

Comment: @David i added the second example because of the scope of function test i expect it will no longer exist after timeout

Comment: @abel-mak But you're not using `setTimeout` correctly. You invoke `console.log` immediately, and pass the return of that to `setTimeout`.  You can clearly see it logs `hello` instantly, and does not wait 10 seconds. Note that, even if you were logging 10 seconds in the future, it still would work just fine. You have the answer you need here: Closures. You should read the linked duplicate or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: @abel-mak   Did you not notice when you run the second snippet, you don't wait 10 seconds?..  You need -> `setTimeout(() =>console.log(x), 10000);`  But even then because of scope capturing it would still work.

Comment: @abel-mak - But it's doing the `console.log`, **then** calling `setTimeout`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643714/settimeout-calls-function-immediately-instead-of-after-delay and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference

Comment: yeah my bad @user229044

Comment: Just a heads up, it's good to see your using `let`, and I assume `const` and not `var`, as that potentially has scope / closure issues.  eg. -> `for (var x = 0; x < 10; x ++) setTimeout(() => console.log(x), 1);`,  <-- use `let` and this magically works.

Comment: i just edit the timeout code thanks guys